# How to split a delimited string into n(n-1)/2 to combinations in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

For example **"red/green/blue"** splits into the following

> `red` `red/green` `red/green/blue`

```
select * from table where column in('red','red/green','red/green/blue');
```

Comment: Please clarify your formula `n(n-1)/2` for number of combinations. If the string is `'red/green/blue/yellow'`, what output do you expect? .  The combinations `red
red/green
red/green/blue
red/green/blue/yellow`  doesn't equal to `4(4-1)/2 = 6`. Show us more examples to cover all your scenarios. Also, what are you searching for from the table? How the data is stored? there could be other options to do the same and you might have presumed splitting is the only option?

Comment: And if you had `red/green/blue/black` what would be the *6* results that you want?

Comment: You are correct Gordon. My bad it is not n(n-1)/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `substr` and `inst` combinations as :

```
with t as
(
select 'red/green/blue' as str from dual
)
select substr(str,1,instr(str,'/',1,1)-1) str1,
       substr(str,1,instr(str,'/',1,2)-1) str2,
       str as str_whole
  from t;

STR1    STR2        STR_WHOLE
----    ----------  --------------
red     red/green   red/green/blue
```

If you wanna get row-wise, you might use by adding `regexp_count` with the following style :

```
with t as
(
select 'red/green/blue' as str from dual
)
select decode(sign(instr(str,'/',1,level)),1,substr(str,1,instr(str,'/',1,level)-1),str)
       as str
  from t
connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'/') + 1; 

STR 
--------------   
red     
red/green   
red/green/blue
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/FZIXNU94903)

Comment: @jamesdean Unfortunately it's impossible to pivot fully-dynamic even if we use `pivot` keyword. Dynamic case works only for `pivot xml` but this is not you want, which extracts only one long string as a result.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @jamesdean but `IN` is not `LIKE`, exact matches occur for `IN`, I mean you should get `UR` values exactly as`'APP/ADMIN/SECURITY'`  or `'APP'`. Please try again.

Comment: @james I saw your last question(`#53357976`). You're on the right way but UID parameter should be `USER1` instead of `USER4` to get 1 for count, since UR for USER1 contains `APP/ADMIN/SECURITY` as one of the components in your queries' list( `'APP,APP/ADMIN/SECURITY'` ).

Comment: @james excuse me, yes UR='APP' for `USER4` and that already returns 1 as count. Please try this demo : https://rextester.com/XGRJD74615

Comment: Thank you for your time and help  @Barbaros